# How to dynamically define different no of rows for different no of sections in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview where i return the no of sections and no of rows for each sections dynamically.  I can implement it like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(  section == 0)
    return [array count];

    if(  section == 1)
    return [array2 count];

    if(  section == 2)
    return [array3 count];
}
```

if i am aware that i have 3 sections i can do it in this above mentioned way. But how to dynamically define the no of rows for different sections. e.g:- u have if(section == 0). i dont want to hard code the value of 0,1,2 here. I am not sure about the total no of sections. How can we do it we want to return the no of rows dynamically for different sections? I have an array to display no of sections and different arrays to display no of rows for each section. How to dynamically mention in the method "numberOfRowsInSection"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you can follow this approach , you can put all your countable arrays in another `NSMutableArray` like lets say tmpArray (e.g. `tmpArray[0] = array` or `tmpArray[1] = array2` , or just by appending `[tmpArray addObject:array] ..)`,

then you can go like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[tmpArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

i hope this will help you to solve your problem ..

Comment: Thanks a lot @iremk .. I hope this works. i ll let u know. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, It works but the problem here is how to update the cell text in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I have taken an NSMutableArray and inserted 3 Arrays into it. Now i want to update the cell text from the 3 arrays appropriately. Any alternative for this? Though i have indexpath.row and indexpath.section in my method, I am getting an uncaught exception. I am trying out this way.. cell.textLabel.text = [[allSectionsArrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Solved it myself....This will get the exact data... " cell.textLabel.text = [[allSectionsArrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; "